# WireMockEducation:test: Could not find com.github.JensPiegsa:wiremock-extension:0.4.0

Tags: java, maven, gradle, wiremock

I tried to add the wiremock-extension to the project, but Gradle can't find the needed repository.

- I take the repo from the official maven repo:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.JensPiegsa/wiremock-extension/0.4.0

- build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "java"
}

....

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/"
    }
}

dependencies {
...
    //wiremock
    testImplementation "com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8-standalone:2.24.1"
    testImplementation group: 'com.github.JensPiegsa', name: 'wiremock-extension', version: '0.4.0'
}
```

The error I received:

> ```
> WireMockEducation:test: Could not find com.github.JensPiegsa:wiremock-extension:0.4.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
>   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/JensPiegsa/wiremock-extension/0.4.0/wiremock-extension-0.4.0.pom
>   - https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/com/github/JensPiegsa/wiremock-extension/0.4.0/wiremock-extension-0.4.0.pom
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, mvnrepository isn't an "official repo". Rather, it is a site that aggregates information from multiple "real" maven repositories, and it might not contain the latest information.

If you look at the actual [Mulesoft repository](https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/com/github/JensPiegsa/wiremock-extension/), you will find that the module is indeed not there anymore (except for some metadata):

```
Index of /repositories/public/com/github/JensPiegsa/wiremock-extension
Name    Last Modified   Size    Description
Parent Directory
maven-metadata.xml.md5  Mon Sep 13 04:55:04 UTC 2021    33  
maven-metadata.xml.sha-256  Mon Sep 13 04:55:04 UTC 2021    65  
maven-metadata.xml.sha-512  Mon Sep 13 04:55:04 UTC 2021    129 
maven-metadata.xml.sha1 Mon Sep 13 04:55:04 UTC 2021    41
```

But from the [project documentation](https://github.com/JensPiegsa/wiremock-extension), you can see that you should use the Jitpack repository instead of Mulesoft:

```java
repositories { 
     mavenCentral()
     maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
dependencies {
    testImplementation "com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8-standalone:2.24.1"
    testImplementation "com.github.JensPiegsa:wiremock-extension:0.4.0"
}
```